WebView не показывает кнопки управления конструктора сайтов
У меня такой вопрос. WebView  не показывает кнопки управления конструктора, сам сайт открывается в WebView, а в браузере Chrom все работает что за причина?

Тысяча причин. Например, не включен javascript. WebView использует голое ядро хрома, сам хром ещё кучу плюшек, надстроек и плагинов

Так и пользуйтесь Хромом в своем приложении: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs
